# Empty dataframe with just indexes and a list of values I want to be columns, how to set this list to columns?

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a list `['A', 'B', 'C']` and a dataframe

```
1
2
3
4
```

The dataframe has no columns as of yet

How can I create a dataframe that looks like this?

```
   A B C
1
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `index` and `column` arguments of dataframe constructor as:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A', 'B', 'C'], 
             index=range(1,5))
```

Output:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | nan | nan | nan |
| 2 | nan | nan | nan |
| 3 | nan | nan | nan |
| 4 | nan | nan | nan |

Comment: Thanks this is it :) I can't accept the answer yet but I will in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dataframe, you can create a column with NaN value by `df[col] = pd.NA`. That's also applied to a list of columns

```py
lst = ['A', 'B', 'C']
df[lst] = pd.NA
```

```
print(df)

      A     B     C
1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
3  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
4  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
```